# Crash recovery in C++

Tags: c++, linux, crash, recovery

I have an application written in C++ in a Linux environment. The app dynamically loads library (shared object) during runtime. (Application gets the user command and it will do the logic to dynamically load the required shared library.)

Is there any way to prevent the application from crashing and exiting when a crash or segfault occurs in the shared library?

I want my application to be active and report the crash to the user.

Comment: cpp is the C preprocessor.  C++ is the language.

Comment: what kind of application is it? How critical is it? Tell us more about it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Itwasntpete answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20853081/841108) you could set (using [sigaction(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) *with* `SA_SIGINFO`, don't use [signal(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html)!) a signal handler for `SIGSEGV`. However, read carefully [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) first.

Notice that if you want to entirely catch `SIGSEGV` (or other asynchronous signals like `SIGBUS`, `SIGILL`, `SIGFPE` etc...) and continue processing, it is tricky and machine specific. If you return plainly from your `SIGSEGV` then the machine state is staying the same, and execution comes back to the machine instruction which has triggered the `SIGSEGV` which becomes re-trigerred *ad infinitum* (you are stuck in an endless loop).

So to be able to continue execution, you should either not return from your signal handler, or use [siglongjmp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/siglongjmp.3.html) in it to jump to a state previously registered with [sigsetjmp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sigsetjmp.3.html), or alter the machine state. To alter the machine state you may change the [address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space) using [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) and related calls, or you may change some [saved] processor registers using the `ucontext_t*` passed as the third argument to your handler, and querying the detail of the signal info using the `siginfo_t*` passed as the second argument. How to do this is system specific (it depends upon the operating system and the processor) and tricky.

If you want to show a nice backtrace from your signal handler, consider using e.g. the [libbacktrace](https://github.com/mirrors/gcc/tree/master/libbacktrace) from inside recent GCC source ball. (It will work much nicer if both the program and the plugin have been compiled with debug info, e.g. with `gcc -O -g`)

Notice that [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) says explicitly that only *async-signal-safe functions* can be called (directly or indirectly) from a signal handler. So in principle, calling `malloc`, `::operator new` (which is called by most [C++ containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container)!!) or `printf` from a signal handler is forbidden, and is not wise. However, if you just call a `libbacktrace` function and then [_exit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/_exit.2.html) from your signal handler, that would often (but in principle, not always) work.

If you want your application to report an error and *stay active* (e.g. if your application is a server, to be able continue serving a lot of requests) it probably would be very tricky (and sometimes impossible). For example, if the plugin is buggy to the point of having [corrupted the heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_corruption), you should clean up the mess (which is not always possible).... In some situations, I would imagine that the only thing to do would be to restart the applcation (e.g. by calling [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) from inside the signal handler). [Application checkpointing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_checkpoint) techniques could be relevant: you could design your application to checkpoint periodically and restart from the latest saved state...

In general **reliable crash recovery is really difficult**, specially for C++ software. You need to understand a lot of implementation details. Using exclusively [free software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) helps a lot: you can study details inside all libraries (even `libstdc++` and `libc`: you may need to understand the internals of implementation of `malloc` ...).

I am not even sure it is the right approach for plugins. You could perhaps consider helping the plugin developer e.g. by expliciting some well defined application specific coding rules (or [programming style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_style)) and perhaps developing some GCC compiler extensions e.g. with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) to check some of them at plugin compilation time.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. [If a segfault occurs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault), your program will first receive the `SIGSEGV` (see [signal](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) or since signal is obsolete [sigaction(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html)). Connecting this signal to a handler allows you to make your crash-report.

```
void crash(int sig) {
  cout << "report crash";
  exit(sig);
}

int main() {
  // connect signal to handler
  signal(SIGSEGV, crash);

  return 0;
}
```

As Jonathan Leffler mentioned is his comment, it is just a small suggestion what to do. There are a few signals which should be catched not only `SIGSEGV`, but maybe also `SIGILL`, `SIGFPE`... depending on your application.

Comment: How well that works depends on the nature of the corruption that induces the segmentation fault.  Also, technically, your signal handler shouldn't call standard I/O functions. Since `exit()` runs things like `atexit()` handlers, it may not be entirely safe, either.  Nevertheless, what you suggest is the core of what to do.

Comment: Notice that [signal(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html) is *obsolete*. Its man page says "Avoid its
use: use [sigaction(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) instead"